# Output 4 set of 7 ascendant ordered and unique random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, duplicates

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to solve my issue here, and I thought why not go here and ask you professionals for some help.

The main thing is, I've only been studying C++ for a few weeks in School, and roughly what 
I've been going through are if/else, for/while/do loops, arrays and obviously some more basic stuff, so my main problem while trying to solve this is whether or not my knowledge is enough?
Would this be easier solved if I read on about vectors etc?

Now, what I have been successful of doing is sorting the numbers which I solved like this:
Basically what I used is an bubble sort algorithm (I think?)

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++) 
{
    for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
        if(slump[j]>random[j+1])        
        {
            temp = random[j];
            slump[j] = random[j+1];
            slump[j+1] = random;        
        }
    }
}
```

However I can't for the life of me figure out how to prevent duplicates from appearing **(there can be duplicates from row to row but not on the same row)** when assigning each index from 0-6 a random number.

```
for(int j=0;j<7;j++) 
{
    random[j] = rand()%40+1;
}
```

I hope I've made myself somewhat clear, as English isn't my native language, please do tell me if I need to clarify anything. And I do hope I can find some help on how to solve this, with a not too complex solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting procedure will not help you to prevent duplicates, so it must be resolved **before**.

First you ensure that there are no duplicated numbers. When you get all the numbers you need.

To ensure that there are no random numbers, two options:

- After each number is generated, check against the numbers already obtained. If it is repeated, discard it and get a new random number.
- Since you want 7 numbers in a 40 wide range, just use it as an order. The first number is picked between 0-39, the second number between 0-38, and so on. Already used numbers are skipped (so, a random sequence of 3-5-2-4 means the number sequence 3-6-2-7)

Comment: No _duplicated_ random numbers?

Comment: As a rule of thumbs, try to divide (*analize*) your problems into several different, smaller (and probably well-known) problems.

Comment: @timrau could you be a little more verbose? It is hard to understand your question.

Comment: @SJuan76 I think timrau's referring to your sentence "First you ensure that there are no random numbers" which sounds like the opposite of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Hey @SJuan76! I will try what you are suggesting as soon as possible, however I might not be able to do it right now since I'm going away over the night. I will return with an answer on how it went, maybe you could post a little "example code" meanwhile? Not the answer, but just something that'll lead me in the right way, if you know what I mean.

Comment: What I mean is I don't quite understand on how to do what you're suggesting after the last "dot". Since if I pick a number between 1-40 first and I get let's say 15, and I then reduce the rand to %39+1, 15 can still appear. I hope I'm not sounding all too stupid

Comment: Also, do you think this problem could be more easily solved if I learned how to use vectors? Since from what I've heard, they are more open to altering/removing indexes.

Comment: But you skip already used values. It could be implemented by a boolean array, when a value is used its position is set to `false/0`; v.g. `used[15]=0`. When you get a new random number, you iterate the array counting non-used positions (so, if you get another 15, it skips it and you get 16). A vector is another possible implementation. Anyway, given that you use 7 numbers in a range of 40 values, I would use the first idea (the second one was because I thought you were using 7 numbers in a range of 7, which would have lead to too many discarded values).

Answer (score 0):

Umm, it shouldn't be too hard to check for duplicates.

You could try the following for instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  random[i] = rand%40 + 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
   {
     if(random[i] == random[j])
     {
        random[i] = rand%40 + 1;
        i = i -1;
        break;
     }
   }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that should be a profecceint check for whether or not a number has been repeated in random[]. Also, even though vectors are more fun and somewhat easier to use they will not make this operation easier.

Hope it helps. =)

Comment: When I try this solution cmd only gives me a blank screen when I run it.